# Why is Hazard Function called rate of failure?

Tags: survival, hazard, weibull-distribution

I am confused why Hazard Function is called rate of failure. Here is what I understood about Hazard Function.

Suppose we are dealing with Weibull and let $f(X)$ be the *pdf*, $F(X)$ be the *cdf*.

Now, I have Reliability $R(X) = 1 - F(X)$. Dividing $f(X)$ with $R(X)$ gives us the *Hazard Function*.

The $f(x)$ gives us the probability of failure and $R(X)$ give us the probability of success. So if we divide the probability of failure by probability of success we get $Failure/Success$. If we call *Hazard* is the rate of failure, then it should be $Failure/SomeInterval$.

Also, if I look at $Kaplan-Meier$ estimate, $h(t)$ i.e. the hazard function estimate is $$ \#\,Items\,failed/ \#\,Items\,in\,Risk$$ but not $$ \#\,Items\,failed/ \#\,Items\,that\, didnt\, fail$$ which I get after dividing $f(X)$ by $R(X)$

This is what I understand but in all books and journals, *Hazard Function* is called rate of failure. Am I missing something??

Comment: Don't you think the number of items at risk is the number of items that haven't failed yet?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ denote time to event. For notation, I'm going to use $x$ instead of $t$, and $S(x)$ ("survival function") instead of $R(x)$. Let's start with a more intuitive definition of the hazard function $h(x)$.:

$$h(x) = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{\Pr(x \leq X < x + \Delta x \mid X \geq x)}{\Delta x}$$.

That is, it is a "conditional event rate". Take the probability that the subject experiences the event "in the next instant" (conditioned on the fact that they've survived up until this point) and divide it by the "length" of the instant to make it into a rate (hand-wavy abuse of limits, but yeah). So $h(x)\cdot \Delta x$ provides an approximation of the probability of an individual of "age" x experiencing the event in the next short time interval.

Now getting from this definition $h(x)$ to the one you're asking about is a matter of algebraic manipulation and calculus:

$$h(x) = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{\Pr(x \leq X < x + \Delta x \mid X \geq x)}{\Delta x}$$

$$= \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{\Pr(x \leq X < x + \Delta x , \hspace{2mm}X \geq x)}{\Delta x \cdot \Pr(X \geq x)}  $$

$$ = \frac{1}{S(X)} \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{\Pr(x \leq X < x + \Delta x , X \geq x)}{\Delta x}  $$

$$ = \frac{1}{S(X)} \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{F(x + \Delta x) - F(x)}{\Delta x}$$

$$ = \frac{dF(x)}{S(x)dx} = - \frac{1}{S(X)}\frac{dS(x)}{dx} = -\frac{dlog[S(x)]}{dx}$$

$$ = \frac{f(x)}{S(x)}$$

Comment: Ok,so _Pr(x<=X<x+dx)_  gives the probability of Failure between _x_ and _x+ dx_. Now this divided by _dx_ is obviously not the rate of failure. To get the rate of failure we need to get rid of the denominator in _Pr(x<=X<x+dx)_ and divide by _dx_. I dont get how the conditional is doing that.